# Variable Importance using Random Forest (Caret)

Tags: r, testing, random-forest, r-caret, training-data

I am using the caret package to carry out a random forest. I have used the following code:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
  method = "repeatedcv",classProbs=FALSE, 
  number = 10,
  ## repeated ten times
  repeats = 10)

set.seed(1)
newrf=train(y ~ ., data = traindata , method = "rf", 
            trControl = fitControl)

rf_imp = varImp(newrf)
```

It works alright and it's a regression model. However, when I use the following to see the importance of the variables I get the following error:

Error in varImp[, "%IncMSE"] : subscript out of bounds

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error says you try to subset nonexisting column. Without sample data its just a wild guess why it happens.

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr. The issue was importance=T missing in the train function. Is there a way to find out the sign (-+) on the variables

Comment: What do you mean "to find out the sign (-+) on the variables"?